# Is $f(\theta)=\cos \theta-\theta$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

My question is very simple, I would like to know if the function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R, f(\theta)=\cos \theta-\theta$ is continuous in every point of the domain? I think yes, because $f$ is the sum of two continuous functions in every point of $\mathbb R$.

Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @Chappers thanks!!!

Comment: Yes.  You're correct.  The sum of continuous functions is a continuous function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is continuous. Addition, subtraction and multiplication are continuous operations on the real line, and composites of continuous maps are continuous.